# Applescript quitting unexpectedly

Tags: macos, loops, applescript

I've made an Applescript script, in which I use af repeat loop to keep it going. The loop is made in such a way, that I can use ESC, or 'Cancel' button, to move backwards when it shows a dialog box or a choose from list box.

However!!! The 'moving back' part works flawlessly when I run the script from the editor, but when I run it as an application it only works half the way back. Once I get to a certain point, the application just closes. It does not give me any crash report or anything, it just closes.

The loop/repeat is as follows:

```
set theAction to "choose type"
set breakRepeat to false

repeat while breakRepeat is false
    if theAction is "choose type" then
        set myType to (choose from list {"Børnehaver", "Skoler"} with title "VÆLG TYPE")
        if myType is "Børnehaver" then
            set myType to "BORNEHAVER"
        else if myType is "Skoler" then
            set myType to "SKOLER"
        else if myType is false then
            try
                set myExit to (button returned of (display dialog "Vil du afslutte?" with title "Afslut?" buttons {"Annullér", "Afslut"} cancel button "Annullér" default button "Afslut"))
            on error
                set myExit to "choose type"
            end try
            if myExit is "Afslut" then
                set breakRepeat to true
            end if
        else
            set theAction to "choose year"
        end if
    else if theAction is "choose year" then
        set theYears to getfolders(alias ((myType & ":") as string), "theYears")
        set chosenYear to choosefromlist(theYears, "alias", false, -2, "VÆLG" & space & myType & "-år", "Vælg skoleår:")
        if chosenYear is false then
            set theAction to "choose type"
        else
            set theAction to "choose school"
        end if
    else if theAction is "choose school" then
        set theSchools to getfolders(chosenYear, "theSchools")
        set chosenSchool to choosefromlist(theSchools, "alias", false, -2, "VÆLG SKOLE:", "Vælg skole:")
        if chosenSchool is false then
            set theAction to "choose year"
        else
            set theAction to "choose UID"
        end if
    else if theAction is "choose UID" then
        try
            set chosenUID to searchjpgs(chosenSchool)
            set chosenUIDfiles to choosefromlist(chosenUID, "alias", false, -1, "VÆLG FIL:", "Vælg fil:")
            if chosenUIDfiles is false then
                set theAction to "choose school"
            else
                set theAction to "info for file"
            end if
        on error
            set theAction to "choose school"
        end try
    else if theAction is "info for file" then
        set theAction to fileinfo(chosenUIDfiles)
    else if theAction is "build package" then
        set chosenPackages to buildpackage(mypackages, chosenUIDfiles)
        if chosenPackages is false then
            set theAction to "choose UID"
        else
            makeprintfiles(chosenUIDfiles, chosenPackages)
            set theAction to "choose UID"
        end if
    end if
end repeat
```

Comment: Unrelated but your code is hard to read due to the many many redundant parentheses. At least you can improve your code  by using `if - else if - endif` chains rather than multiple  `if - else if` expressions. Another redundant part is the last `else` in the first `if` (`mytype`) block. It will be never reached because the result of `choose from list` can only be the two list items or `false`. And why is `action` a list? In the code the list contains always only one item.

Comment: @vadian _"Another redundant part is the last `else` in the first `if` (`mytype`) block. It will be never reached"_  I thought this too - it _shouldn't_ be possible given what I understand about how conventional `if...then...else` expressions work in many other languages (with a couple of exceptions, of which I didn't think AppleScript was one).  However, if you run the script, and insert a marker inside that clause, the script clearly gets there, seemingly from right out of one of the first two clauses where `myType`'s value is changed.  Surely this is a bug in AppleScript, and a new one...?!

Comment: Although, I'm still running on this: **System info:** _AppleScript version:_ `2.7`  _System version:_ `10.13.6`

Comment: Thanks, guys...

I tried the proposed edit, however even with a couple of edits I couldn't get it to run properly. And it didn't help with the initial problem I had :-/

I still have no idea why the loop works fine when I run it from the editor, but it still shuts down (no error message or anything) when I run it as an application...